# How to use case statement in these two tables

Tags: sql

In SQL I have created a temporary table as shown below:

| Rank | Rate | Roles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | V High | !A!B!C!D! |
| 2 | High | !D!F!B!H! |
| 3 | Low | !F!B!P!K! |
| 4 | V Low | !P!Q!A!H! |

Higher rate (ex. High (Rank 2)) role (ex. F) can approve lower Rate records ( ex. High to V Low (Rank 2-4)) but not higher Rate records (ex. V High (Rank 1)).
For any multi appearing Role we need to consider higher Rank (i.e. Rank has low value). ex. For role F, higher rank should be considered as 2(i.e. High) since it appear in both High and Low rows.

Below is sample data for permanent table. In actual it has lots of data.

| Rate | Role |
| --- | --- |
| Low | Q |
| Low | H |
| V High | H |
| Low | D |
| V Low | A |
| High | C |
| High | Q |

Now different Roles in temporary table need to be compared with Role in actual table.
So as for below record:

| Rate | Role |
| --- | --- |
| Low | Q |

as Q is only present in 'V Low'(Rank 4) so he can't approve  'Low' level. So Flag need to be set to 1. If role can approve record then flag need to set to 0.

Similarly output should look like below for others:

| Rate | Role | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Low | Q | 1 |
| Low | H | 0 |
| V High | H | 1 |
| Low | D | 0 |
| V Low | A | 0 |
| High | C | 0 |
| High | Q | 1 |

Please help me with this how i can achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be many different ways of achieving this, but one possible method is something like:

```
SELECT
 t1.rate,
 t1.role,
 CASE WHEN (SELECT min(rank) FROM temptable t3 WHERE t3.roles LIKE concat('%!', t1.role, '!%')) <= t2.rank THEN 0 ELSE 1 END flag
FROM maintable t1 INNER JOIN temptable t2
  on t1.rate = t2.rate
```

The join on `t1.rate = t2.rate` is so that you can get the numeric value of the rank. The subquery in the `SELECT` get the "highest" rank for their role (which is actually the `min` numeric value) and the `CASE` statement compares it to the value from the main (non temporary) table.

Note that I used `concat` in the subquery since I think most modern DBMSes support it, but you could use something else to be consistent with the rest of your queries (e.g. `'%!'+t1.role+'!%'` in SQL Server or `'%!'||t1.role||'!%'` in Oracle).

I think this is a reasonable query, but there will be many different ways of doing this. Hopefully this helps you.